# List<> failing to serialize to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using the following C# `class` in my ASP.NET MVC project:

```
public class ZoneModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool LineFault { get; set; }
    public bool Sprinkler { get; set; }
    public int Resistance { get; set; }
    public string ZoneVersion { get; set; }
    List<DetectorModel> Detectors { get; set; }
}
```

In one of my `Controller`s, I have an `Action` with a return type of `JsonResult`, from which I return a list of `ZoneModel` objects (populated from the database). The `Detectors` property contains data, but when I return the list from the controller using `return Json(viewModel);`, the list of detectors is missing from the serialized response.

Why is the `Detectors` property not serializing to JSON?

Comment: Try making the Detectors public.

Comment: Seems that I looked over it. Made it public and now it works.

Comment: @wellers You should post the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify my comment. Properties need to be declared as Public members in order to be Serialized by either JSON.NET or the built-in JavaScriptSerializer.

```
public class ZoneModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool LineFault { get; set; }
    public bool Sprinkler { get; set; }
    public int Resistance { get; set; }
    public string ZoneVersion { get; set; }

    // this property will not be serialized since it is private (by default)
    List<DetectorModel> Detectors { get; set; }
}
```